# Refreshing a fragment from a DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-dialogfragment

I've been going around in circles trying to do something that seems pretty basic.  I have a `DialogFragment` that accepts a users input, then, on submission, refreshes a `ListView` in a `Fragment` that is part of a `ViewPager`.

I have everything working except the `Fragment` with the `ListView` does not refresh itself.  It's a little confusing though, because it does refresh the data, but I have to swipe a couple views, then back again to see the updated data.

After doing some research, I'm supposed to use `getItemPosition` and `notifyDataSetChanged` on the `ViewPager` and it should work. The problem is that calling `notifyDataSetChanged` results in a `Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions` exception being thrown:

**Main Activity**

```
public class Main extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements MyListFragment.OnRefreshAdapterListener, DialogConfirmation.OnRefreshKeywordsListener //Updated Code
{
    private static List<Fragment> fragments;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle)
    {    
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    { 
        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        fragments.add(new MyListFragment()); //fragment with the ListView

        fragments.add(MyDetailFragment.newInstance(0));
        fragments.add(MyDetailFragment.newInstance(1));
        fragments.add(MyDetailFragment.newInstance(2));

        mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);
    }

    private static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {  

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {  
             super(fm);  
        }  

        @Override  
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {
            return fragments.get(index);
        }  

        @Override
        public int getCount() {  
             return 4;  
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
   }

    @Override
    public void onRefreshAdapterListener() {
        this.mMyFragmentPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //Updated Code
    @Override
    public void onRefreshTextListener() {
        MyListFragment tf = (MyListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentText);

        if (tf == null)
            tf = (MyListFragment)this.fragments.get(0);

            tf.RefreshText();       
    }
}
```

**ListFragment**

```
public class MyListFragment extends SherlockListFragment
{
    OnRefreshAdapterListener mRefreshAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {

        adapter = new CustomAdapter();

        /*code to add items to adapter */

        this.setListAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null && getArguments().getString("text").length() > 0)
        {
            SaveText(getArguments().getString("text"));
            this.mRefreshAdapter.onRefreshAdapterListener(); //this line causes a "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions" exception
        }

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.listing, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        mRefreshAdapter = (OnRefreshAdapterListener)activity;
    }

    public interface OnRefreshAdapterListener {
        public void onRefreshAdapterListener();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDialogTextAdd(final String text) {
    }   
}
```

**DialogFragment**

```
public class DialogTextAdd extends DialogFragment implements OnEditorActionListener {

    private EditText mText;
    OnRefreshTextListener mTextKeywords; //Updated Code

    public interface DialogTextAddListener {
        void onDialogTextAdd(final String inputText);
    }

    public DialogTextAdd() {
        // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
    }

    //Updated Code
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity act) {
        super.onAttach(act);
        mTextKeywords = (OnRefreshTextListener)act;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_edit, container);
        mText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.text_add);
        getDialog().setTitle("Add Text");

        // Show soft keyboard automatically
        mText.requestFocus();
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
        mText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(final TextView v, final int actionId, final KeyEvent event) {
        if (EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE == actionId) {

            MyListFragment mf = new MyListFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("text", mText.getText().toString());
            mf.setArguments(args);

            //this seems to be intefering with the notifyDataSetChanged in the listing fragment
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(mf, "my_fragment").commit();

            mTextKeywords.onRefreshTextListener(); //Updated Code

            this.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you considered using the setTarget() function of fragments?

Comment: If you have the reference to the `ListFragment` stored in a list what is stopping you from updating that reference(of course first testing before if the fragment's view is not null) with calling an update method on it? What exactly are you trying to do by creating that `MyListFragment` instance and adding it to the activity with the transaction?

Comment: Well, I needed to pass the text input back to the `Fragment`, which is why I created the `MyListFragment` instance with the arguments.  That is what I came up with after looking through examples.  I'm pretty knew to working with `Fragments` and they have my head spinning, so if you can recommend a better way, I'm all ears.  Thanks.

Comment: @Luksprog I ended up figuring out a solution.  I created a `Listener` in my `Activity` which either gets the `Fragment` from the `FragmentManager` or just gets the `Fragment` from the list of `Fragments` and runs a method that updates the keywords.  Not 100% that is the best way, but it's working.  I updated the OP putting comments in with the next code.

Comment: Well it's basically what I already said. You'll **always** get the fragment reference from the list because the line `(MyListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentText);` will always return null.

Comment: @Luksprog Well, I have another layout which displays both `Fragments` (for tablets), and it doesn't use a `ViewPager`, which is why I have that conditional statement there.  Either way, thanks for your help. If you want to add a proper response, I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have everything working except the Fragment with the ListView does
>   not refresh itself.

There is no point on creating and adding to the `FragmentActivity` a new instance of `MyListFragment`. From your code it appears that you store the fragments that you use in a list so you have references to them(also, just out of curiosity, did you setup the fragments in portrait, did a rotation of the phone and retried to use the `DialogFragment`?). Having references to those fragment means you could always get them from the list and use them to call a refresh/update method.